# Can we do DML in batch APEX start method

Tags: apex, batch

Is there a possibility to insert records in the batch Apex's start method?

Comment: Yes, I think you can, can you add more details here like what you have tried so far and what is not working?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093SzIAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch Apex's **start** method is used to collect the records or objects to be passed to the execute method for processing. It is not recommended to insert records in the start method, as it may cause **performance issues** or **governor limits** errors.

Instead, you can insert records in the **execute** method, which is called for each batch of records returned by the start method. You can use the `Database.BatchableContext` parameter to access the job ID and the scope parameter to access the records in each batch. You can also use the `Database.SaveResult` class to handle the results of the insert operation.

Alternatively, you can use the **Queueable Apex** interface to create asynchronous jobs that can insert records. **Queueable Apex** allows you to chain jobs, pass parameters, and monitor the status of the jobs. You can use the System.enqueueJob method to add a job to the queue and the `System.QueueableContext` parameter to access the job ID.

For more information refer to this:

- [Batch Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)
- [Queueable Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)